# I have multiple links on the same location (to same a href link). a:visited changes them all when one is clicked. Can I keep each separate?

Tags: css, hover, visited

> I tried to use a class and also tried to use unique classes for each link, but I'm still getting all links "visited" one only one is clicked.  I'm wondering if there's a way to have each "visited" uniquely even if a href goes to same place.  Thank you so much.

```css
a.bluelist:link{
  color:#00a9ff; 
}

a.bluelist:hover{
color: #4dc3ff;
}

a.bluelist:visited{
color: #b99aff;
}

/*next option I tried is to change and make classes unique*/

a.bluelist1:link{
  color:#00a9ff; 
}

a.bluelist1:hover{
color: #4dc3ff;
}

a.bluelist1:visited{
color: #b99aff;
}

a.bluelist2:link{
  color:#00a9ff; 
}

a.bluelist2:hover{
color: #4dc3ff;
}

a.bluelist2:visited{
color: #b99aff;
}

a.bluelist3:link{
  color:#00a9ff; 
}

a.bluelist3:hover{
color: #4dc3ff;
}

a.bluelist3:visited{
color: #b99aff;
}

a.bluelist4:link{
  color:#00a9ff; 
}

a.bluelist4:hover{
color: #4dc3ff;
}

a.bluelist4:visited{
color: #b99aff;
}
```

```html
<a href="#gohere" class="bluelist">Text1</a>     
<br>

<a href="#gohere" class="bluelist">Text2</a>     
<br>
<a href="#gohere" class="bluelist">Text3</a>     
<br>
<a href="#goelsewhere" class="bluelist">Text4</a>   
<br>

/*Next option I tried is here*/

<a href="#gohere" class="bluelist1">Text1</a>    
<br>
<a href="#gohere" class="bluelist2">Text2</a>    
<br>
<a href="#gohere" class="bluelist3">Text3</a>    
<br>
<a href="#goelsewhere" class="bluelist4">Text4</a>
```

Comment: great question, I'm going to edit it to make it a little bit clearer

Comment: one way is to use a `onClick` handler that passes the class as a param to it's callback, and from the call back function, use `Document.querySelector('.class')` to grab that element and update it's styles. there may be a better approach tho ;)